# Arduino Esplora

Tags: programming

So I'm trying to turn my Arduino Esplora into a controller, and my first step is to understand how the controller works. I've copied and pasted this code into the Arduino 1.8.2 IDE.

```
Esplora.writeRGB(255, 255, 255); // sets red, green and blue all to full brightness
```

But I get an error saying,

exit status 1
'Esplora' does not name a type

Please explain why it's doing this.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code, not just a snippet.   Make sure all the library names are shown, all the variable declarations, and all the function definitions – so people don't have to waste time guessing what you did or what you meant.  Also make it verifiable, ie so it can be compiled and tested, allowing other people to test their theories about the problem.

Comment: Please also take the tour at http://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot:

- To include Esplora.h in your sketch.
- To select "Esplora" for the board.